# iOS Swift Detect If Bluetooth Keyboard Is Connected

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth, keyboard

How can I detect if a Bluetooth keyboard is connected to the iPad?  It's actually a barcode scanner but acts as a keyboard.  I want to alert the user if the scanner is not connected.